# Problemas ao efetuar um POST de um MODEL com AJAX no ASP.NET CORE MVC

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, ajax, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-5

Estou com problemas para fazer um post de um modelcomplexo usando o AJAX no Asp.net. O Modeltem algumas propriedades que representam outros Models, mas no momento, eu só preciso inicializá-las com NULL. Eu não sei o que está faltando, mas meu controlador está recebendo valor "nulo" ... Há algum problema na conversão feita no lado do cliente. Eu fiz um teste usando um model simples com 3 campos (int, string e bool) e funcionou corretamente... Só estou tendo problemas se usar esse tipo de Model quq citei na pergunta. Será que é alguma coisa relacionada às propriedades setadas com NULL?  Alguém sabe como me ajudar?

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

```
var pessoaContatoViewModel = {
    Id: 0,
    PessoaId: 0,
    FormaContatoId: formaContatoId,
    FormaContatoDescricao: '',
    FormasContatos: null,
    ContatosTipos: null,
    FormaContatoTipoId: 0,
    Contato: contato,
    Observacao: observacao,
    ContatoPrincipal: contatoPrincipal,
    PessoaContatoChamadaViewModel: null,
    PessoaContatoRedeSocialViewModel: null,
    PessoaContatoEmailViewModel: null
};

$.ajax({
    url: "/pessoa-gerenciar/changeFormaContato",
    type: "POST",
    data: JSON.stringify(pessoaContatoViewModel),
    contentType: "application/json",
    dataType: "json",
    success: function (result) {
        alert('ok');
    },
    error: function () {
        alert("Oops! Algo deu errado.");
        console.log(pessoaContatoViewModel);
    }
});


[HttpPost]
[Route("pessoa-gerenciar/changeFormaContato")]
public IActionResult ChangeFormaContato([FromBody] PessoaContatoViewModel pessoaContatoViewModel)
{
    //ViewBag.indice_new = indice;
    //return PartialView("~/Views/Pessoa/PessoaContato/_PessoaContatoAdd.cshtml", _pessoaContatoAppService.CreateNew(pessoaNatureza, formaContatoId));
    return null;
}


public class PessoaContatoViewModel
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public int PessoaId { get; set; }

    [DisplayName("Forma de Contato")]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Escolha a Forma de Contato")]
    [JsonConverter(typeof(StringEnumConverter))]
    public int FormaContatoId { get; set; }
    public string FormaContatoDescricao { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> FormasContatos { get; set; }

    public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> ContatosTipos { get; set; }

    [DisplayName("Forma de Contato")]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Selecione uma Forma de Contato")]
    public int FormaContatoTipoId { get; set; }

    [DisplayName("Contato")]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "O campo Contato é obrigatório")]
    [MaxLength(100, ErrorMessage = "O campo {0} deve ter no máximo {1} caracteres")]
    public string Contato { get; set; }

    [DisplayName("Observação")]
    [MaxLength(150, ErrorMessage = "O campo {0} deve ter no máximo {1} caracteres")]
    public string Observacao { get; set; }

    [DisplayName("Principal")]
    public bool ContatoPrincipal { get; set; }

    public FormaContatoTipoViewModel FormaContatoTipoViewModel { get; set; }
    public PessoaContatoChamadaViewModel PessoaContatoChamadaViewModel { get; set; }
    public PessoaContatoRedeSocialViewModel PessoaContatoRedeSocialViewModel { get; set; }
    public PessoaContatoEmailViewModel PessoaContatoEmailViewModel { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Dentro do seu ajax tente usar `JSON.stringify({data: pessoaContatoViewModel})`